# How to Share Angular Components Between Projects

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-components

I have one angular project **Project1** with services, models, components, interceptors etc.

Now I want to create another angular project **Project2**, but I want to be like **Project1** and to have all services, components etc, except `.css` and `.html`, because all I want is just to change the colors, and a little bit of `html`.

Is there a way to achieve this without the need to copy everything? Also if I make changes to for example, some service in **Project1**, I want that to be updated in **Project2**.

Comment: How about creating a library? https://angular.io/guide/libraries

Comment: I've heard about modules https://angular.io/guide/architecture-modules

Comment: You can consider an Nx monorepo

Comment: Read https://nx.dev/l/a/core-concepts/why-monorepos and get started here https://nx.dev/l/a/getting-started/nx-setup